# DRF Response isn't working with class based views in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-class-based-views

I am converting my function-based views to class-based views. Following the official documentation, I was getting errors using the Response imported from rest_framework. When using HttpResponse it's working fine. The error I am getting with Response is:

`.accepted_renderer not set on Response`

This is my view:

```
    
    def get(self, request):
        users = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

What could be the reason for this?

serializer:

```
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of this:

```
return Response(serializer.data)
```

try this:

```
return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK) #Status is depends on your code
```

I think your serializer is not saved so that's why you are getting that error

```
    def get(self, request):
        users = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(users, data=request.data, many=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK) 

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Final thing try this.

Comment: Tried this, getting the error of 'status' is not defined

Comment: Then import it               from rest_framework import status

Comment: imported, the undefined error went away but the original error still persists

Comment: Please provide serializers.py file

Comment: added on original comment

Comment: tried this, got this error: Cannot call `.is_valid()` as no `data=` keyword argument was passed when instantiating the serializer instance.

Comment: I have added in serializer = (user, data=request.data, many=true)  above error will solve

Comment: Sorry, this didn't work either